# Keras isn't raising Tensorflow errors?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm writing a custom Tensorflow loss function for Keras, and I tried debugging it by using Tensorflow assertions, but these don't seem to raise errors anywhere even when I'm sure they ought to. I can boil it down to the following example:

```python
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def demo_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    tf.assert_negative(tf.ones([1,1]))
    return tf.square(y_true - y_pred)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=demo_loss)
model.fit(np.ones((1000,1)), np.ones((1000,1)), epochs=10, batch_size=100)
```

This really seems to me like it should emit an `InvalidArgumentError`. Why doesn't it?

(Alternately, what's the more sensible way to debug my custom loss functions?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TensorFlow code is not working because there is nothing which forces the assertion to be executed. To make it work you need to add a control dependency to it, something like:

```
def demo_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assert_negative(tf.ones([1,1]))]):
        return tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the code should stop... your loss function will be compiled together with your model in a single graph, and that `tf.assert` command is totally disconnected from everything.

These functions are not meant to be debugged. They're created to achieve the highest performance possible, that's why it's made first as a graph, and only later you feed the data.

When I want to debug, I go for a little model and predict:

```
trueInput = Input(outputShape)
predInput = Input(outputShape)

output = Lambda(lambda x: demo_loss(x[0],x[1]))([trueInput,predInput])

debugModel = Model([trueInput,predInput], output)
```

Now use this model to predict:

```
retults = degugModel.predict([someNumpyTrue, someNumpyPred])
```

You can divide the function in smaller functions, each one in a different Lambda layer, and see each output separately.